# how to access retry-after in jsoup response when receive HttpStatusException?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am making an HTTP get request using JSoup with the following code:

```
Connection.Response response = null;
try
{
    response = Jsoup.connect(urlstr).execute();
    // do something with response
}
catch (final HttpStatusException e)
{
    if (e.getStatusCode() == 429)
    {
        // how to access retry-after header here since response is null?
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, the only way to get the response headers (which contains the retry-after header that says how long to delay) is to get the JSoup Connection.Response (can call headers().get("retry-after)), which according to the documentation can only be obtained after the connection is executed.  However, the execute call throws an exception which lands me in the catch block with the response null.

The only thing I have access to is the HttpStatusException which does not have access to the response headers.  Not sure if every 429 request would fail this way but I am at a loss in my particular case as to how to access the retry-after header so I can delay the appropriate amount of time.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could do the request using some other HTTP client and then parse the body with jsoup.

Comment: When Exception occurs that means no other object is returned so `// do something with response` line is not supposed to be executed and if the Exception object does not contain your desired data, you sure are out of luck. There is no way to get that data with Jsoup.